# How to track individual JavaScript Processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The title is likely misleading for I'm not sure how to summarize my question in one sentence.

I have a scenario where my script has to post data to multiple URLs in parallel and I'm struggling to figure out how to visually track what's happening with each individual URL (i.e. what's being posted and what's being returned). Here is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const postData = async (order_id) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        let data = await grabDataFromSomewhere(...);
        await axios.post(`http://example.net/orders/${order_id}`, {data})
            .then(response => {
                //console.log(response.data);
                console.log(i, `POSTING TO http://example.net/orders/${order_id}`);
                console.log("--- Response:", response.data)
            })
    }
}

const orders = ['5f96499a3a19135ad163', '99a3a19135ad1630238', '6499a3a19135ad16302']

orders.forEach(id => {
    postData(id)
})
```

The script works well in terms of posting the right data to the right URL, but the console output, obviously, is one big mess as all the axios requests finish and and dump its output to the same console.

What's the best way to keep an eye on the output of each individual call to the `postData` function in its own dedicated console?

For those who use *screen* on Linux, a good way to visualize what I'm looking for is imagining each call to `postData` spawning a new screen which I can attach any time and see the function's output.

Comment: I output log data with a prefix using https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-annotate.  Either that, or with a tag in entries in a JSON log.  From there, it's easy enough to `tail` with `grep` live as-needed.

Comment: I see. So the premise is to still dump all output into one pile, but make it easier to later parse through it. I suppose I could do that. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at `console.table()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Comment: You're already logging `i` so you should be able to tell which output in the console belongs to which `axios.post()` call.  What else are you trying to see?

Comment: Well ```i``` is not very telling because there will be many identical i's as the for loop runs over and over for each URL. But I could log some other identifying info as suggested by Brad and then have an easier time parsing the output.

Comment: So, you're calling this function over and over again and thus have multiple instances of this function in flight at the same time?  Then, create some identifier that you pass into the function (perhaps can use the order_id) and log that too with every `console.log()`.  The whole idea is to log enough information that you can reconstruct exactly what happened for every function call.

Comment: You could also queue all the log statements into an array and then log them all at once (so they would be all together) when the `for` loop is done.  This wouldn't let you see real-time, but would make it easier to see all the log data for one `postData()` call all together when it was done.

Comment: Ah queuing up log statements in an array is something I haven't thought of. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following code. The idea is to make all the requests in parallel, but to log them in the order that they are sent out. If you run the following code and check the console, you will see that the responses occur at random intervals, but that they are always logged in the correct order in the browser. The trick is to create a map of promises representing the post requests, then chain them in such a way that when the first request returns, it is logged, then when the second one returns it is logged, and so on. If a request returns out of order, its promise will still be resolved, but we will only log it once all of its predecessors have arrived.

I realise this is not exactly what you were asking for, but this is how I would go around trying to solve the problem that you are facing.

Also, you have a multi-dimensional array, so I would flatten that out into a single-dimensional one before mapping its contents to Ajax requests.

This solution is based on an article by Jake Archibald https://web.dev/promises/

```js
const orders = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon']

function postToAxios(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('in set timeout', data);

      if (data === 'beta') {
        reject('rejected: ' + data);
      } else {
        resolve('resolved: ' + data);
      }
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

function createLogEntry(data) {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = "log-entry";
  el.textContent = data;
  return el;
}

function createErrorEntry(data) {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = "error-entry";
  el.textContent = data;
  return el;
}

orders.map(postToAxios)
  .reduce(function(sequence, promise) {
    return sequence
      .then(function() {
        return promise;
      }).then(function(result) {
        log.append(createLogEntry(result))
      }, function(reason) {
        log.append(createErrorEntry(reason));
      });
  }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    console.log('all done');
  });
```

```css
.log-entry,
.error-entry {
  margin: 5px;
  border: dotted 1px grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.error-entry {
  color: red;
  border-color: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: As you point out, it's not precisely what I was looking for, but this, nonetheless, is a pretty neat piece of code and I will most certainly find great use for it.